# The memory information is different between psensors and gnome-system-monitor

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

I am using Ubuntu to run some calculation, so I'd like to check the memory usage during the calculation. But the information from gnome-system-monitor and psensors is different.
As shown in the following screenshot, in the gnome-system-monitor, only 30.4% of memory is used, but in the psensors window, only 13% of memory is still free to use.
My question is:
Which one is right?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"30.4% of memory is used", it's implies that your computer RAM used 30.4%. You will get same result on another system monitor like bpytop(https://snapcraft.io/install/bpytop/ubuntu).

Comment: What is the info showed in psensors?